# Implicit conversion from datatype 'INT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to insert data into a table and getting

> implicit conversion error.

Can someone please help with the syntax?

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
Column1 varchar(30) NOT NULL
Column2 Char(12) NOT NULL
)

Insert Into A (Column1 ,Column2 )
VALUES ('TX ID',convert(char(12), -700))
```

Comment: @Sami I am still seeing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not the missing "," in the Table Creation after `NOT NULL`? I did not get this Error after correcting that.

[No Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwdDM.png)

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
Column1 varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Column2 Char(12) NOT NULL
)

Insert Into A (Column1 ,Column2 )
VALUES ('TX ID',convert(char(12), -700))
```

or a Cast

```
VALUES ('TX ID',cast(-700 as char(12)))
```

Comment: Sorry my bad I missed to add ",". But that is not the issue. I am still seeing the error "Implicit conversion from datatype 'INT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed"

Comment: Does a Cast work as `CREATE TABLE b
(
Column1 varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Column2 char(12) NOT NULL
)

Insert Into b (Column1 ,Column2)
VALUES ('TX ID',cast(-500 as char(12)))`

Comment: Even cast wasn't working. I had dropped and recreated the table and now I'm able to insert using both convert & cast